# URL encoding with Javascript and then decoding with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, urlencode, url-encoding, urldecode

I am wanting to url encode a string with Javascript, with the relevant part of the code being:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

or the full line:

```
<select name="category" onChange="javascript:document.location.href='<? echo '/' . $state . '/dir/'; ?>' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

How can I url encode this with JS and then safely decode it with PHP using `urldecode`?

Comment: check this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem when I wanted to use & in URL. I just solved it using `encodeURIComponent()`.

I used it in onchange function of my dropdown element like this:

```
onchange="window.location='test.php?c='+encodeURIComponent(this.value)"
```

It works well in my case.

I tried to use php function `urlencode()` for this, but I couldn't do that.

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 options:

- `escape()` will not encode: `@*/+`
- `encodeURI()` will not encode: `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`
- `encodeURIComponent()` will not encode: `~!*()'`

Comment: So how to encode html like for example `<dl><dt>Coffe & Cake?</dt><dd>Yes<dd></dl>`, to pass into a URL with JS like for example `?list=<dl><dt>Coffe & Cake?</dt><dd>Yes<dd>`? And then receive it with PHP?